# How to obtain nested fields within JSON

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Background:

I wish to update a nested field within my JSON document. I want to query for all of the "state" that equal "new"

```
      {
          "id": "123"
          "feedback" : {
             "Features" : [
                              {
                                "state":"new"
                              }
        

                          ]
     }
```

This is what I have tried to do:

Since this is a nested document. My query looks like this:

```
   SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.feedback.Features.state = "new"
```

However, I keep ending up with zero results when I know that this exists within the database. What am I doing wrong? Maybe I am getting 0 results because the Features is an array?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just to clarify: You tagged this as `[mongodb]` but your example query is based on the native SQL API. Can you please confirm that you're using the SQL API?

Comment: I will remove this tag. I added MongoDB since I am thinking CosmosDB and MongoDB follow similar processes

Comment: Thank you @ponury-kostek, I tried this and still no results. I think this is because the feedback is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays, you'll need to use `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`. For example, in your case:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.feedback.Features,{'state': 'new'}, true)
```

The 3rd parameter specifies that you're searching within documents within the array, not scalar values.

Comment: thank you @davidmakogon  Is my approach correct for my most recent question? How to query for multiple conditions within nested JSON document? Please give any suggestion. I have read through the documentation and it looks like I have to do a WHERE EXISTS...