# How can I query Cosmos DB with ARRAY_CONTAINS using SqlParameters when the Array contains JSON Objects

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Given the following query

```
SELECT * FROM root r WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@types, r.Type)
```

I want to build a `SQLQuerySpec` like this

```
private SqlQuerySpec BuildQuery(IEnumerable<MyType> search)
{
     var queryText = "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@types, r.Type)";
     //What is the required <structure/Type> of the second 
     //parameter to the constructor of <SqlParameter>?
     //so it becomes a JSON object/JSON Array
     var param = new SqlParameter("@types", search.ToArray())
     var parameters = new SqlParameterCollection{param};
     return new SqlQuerySpec() {QueryText = queryText, Parameters = parameters};
}
```

where the array of `MyType` would look like this (JSON)

```
[
    {key: "A", value: 1},
    {key: "B", value: "Something else"}
]
```

so the resulting query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM root r WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS([
    {key: "A", value: 1},
    {key: "B", value: "Something else"}
], r.Type)
```

and a document of the root collection would look like this

```
{
    "Text": "I wanna be selected by you",
    "Type": {"key": "A", "value": 1}
}
```

and should therefore be picked up by the above query.
Where as this document wouldnt be picked up

```
{
    "Text": "Nah, you not gonna find me",
    "Type": {"key": "C", "value": 1}
}
```

So basically how can I search for an array of JSON objects?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a sample document.

Comment: FYI your `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` example doesn't look right. Needs a 3rd parameter, set to `true`, to specify that you're searching json objects and not just scalar values. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63400144/272109) for an example.